# Spring JmsTemplate connection pooling

Tags: spring, connection, pooling, jmstemplate

we have scenario where the queue name is dynamically changed based on certain transaction,we will be using IBM mq for queueing.My question is that if I define the `JmsTemplate` as request scope bean which will allow modification of queue name dynamically for each request, will connection pooling mechanism work with `JmsTemplate`. we are using spring caching factory mechanism.

Please help on this.

Comment: Why so complex... Just use the send methods that take a destination instead of relying on the default destination... NO need to mess around with scopes and aop...

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum,Yes it would work i guess.probably i dont know how on earth i missed this.

Comment: M. Deinum, Also can u please enlighten me whether creating new jmstemplate object for will nullify connection pooling mechanism.

Comment: NO it won't nor should you be creating new `JmsTemplate` . Just create one and use that, the `JmsTemplate` is threadsafe so no need to construct new ones each time you need one.